# How to use method put on node.js with express for update info

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pug

I'm trying to create a CRUD with nodejs with express and mongoose, when i try to update the content from the form, this empty all the registers when i do it with POST method. Here comes my code:

**Jade template**

```
extends ../includes/layout

block content
  div(class="wrap")
    include ../includes/header
    div(class="column-group vertical-space")
      div(class="all-50 push-center")
        div(class="all-100")
          h1 #{title}
        div(class="all-100")
          form(role="form" method="post" action="#{project.id}" enctype="multipart/form-data")
            div(class="all-50")
              h3 Cambiar nombre a #{project.ProjectName}
              input(type="text" name="projectName" required)
              p Cambiar detalles
              textarea(name="details")
              p Cambiar precio
              input(type="number" name="ammount")
              p Cambiar localización
              input(type="text" name="localize")
            div(class="all-50")
              p Cambiar Imágen
              input(type="file" name="image" multiple)
              //p #{plane}
              //input(type="file" name="plane")
            div(class="all-100")
              button(type="submit") Enviar



    div(class="push")
  include ../includes/footer
```

**controller**

```
saveEditProject : function (req, res, file){
      Project.findById(req.params.id, function(err, project){
        if(!project){
          res.redirect('/project');
        }
        project.ProjectName = req.body.projectName;
        project.ProjectDetails = req.body.details;
        project.ProjectAmount = req.body.ammount;
        project.ProjectLocation = req.body.localize;
        project.ProjectFileName = req.body.image;
        project.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                res.send("not now");
            }
            res.redirect('/project');
        });

      });
    },
```

**route**

```
router.post('/edit/:id', controller.saveEditProject);
```

Comment: Use [`router.put`.](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.METHOD)

Comment: in this way just got http://localhost:3000/project/edit/5734b65f5e8cc78d277e63dc?projectName=testing&details=&ammount=&localize=&image=13122913_798137460320744_2366020950260825105_o.jpg on the browser but nothing is saved on the database

Comment: Are you sure `project` is not `null` ?

Comment: when i render the page i can get the values ej. #{project.ProjectName} for read

Comment: You should use `console.log` to be sure.

Comment: on a get this is what returns console.log(projects); GET /userFiles/projectImage/undefined 500 11.093 ms - 1730
{ __v: 0,
  ProjectOwner: '5720977ffe0697f51001c9a1',
  _id: 5734b65f5e8cc78d277e63dc }

Comment: Marcos, first and foremost catch your err variable in the beginning. Do something else: in the beginning of your findById (right before your current if(!project) write console.log('err: ' + err); console.log('project ' + project); console.log('req.body ' + req.body); see what is returned from that. Do you get an error? Do you get a project? Can you get your body info?

Comment: **err** null
**project**{ __v: 0,
  ProjectOwner: '5720977ffe0697f51001c9a1',
  _id: 5734b65f5e8cc78d277e63dc }
**req.body**[object Object]
{ __v: 0,
  ProjectOwner: '5720977ffe0697f51001c9a1',
  _id: 5734b65f5e8cc78d277e63dc,
  ProjectName: undefined,
  ProjectDetails: undefined,
  ProjectAmount: undefined,
  ProjectLocation: undefined,
  ProjectFileName: undefined }

Comment: Alright so. As you can see your body is undefined and that is your problem. The [object Object] is because we're doing a console.log on it, you can break it down by saying console.log('body projectname:  ' + req.body.projectName); and now you can modify your jade. I don't know anything about jade but I think it looks fine after a fast search in Google. Do you have var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); in your server.js ?

Comment: yes, i got it, comes with the express generator.

Comment: I'm out of ideas honestly. Unfortunately I cannot test the code at the moment and I can't for the next hours. If I were you I'd remove the encType from jade form and I would change action="#{project.id}" to action="/#{project.id}" to see if it produced any different behaviour although I never worked with jade so I'm not sure if I'm telling you makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111859/discussion-between-fpj-and-marcos-r-guevara).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BodyParser isn't meant for image uploading so make sure you have for example **[multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)** in your **server.js**:

```
var multer  = require('multer')
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
```

Then just follow their page and for example do this:

```
router.post('/edit/:id',  upload.array(), controller.saveEditProject);
```

The key here is to use a parser that deals with images. You have in your Jade form the following attribute:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

That is what will "disable" BodyParser because it will not interpret it. If you take it out you will see BodyParser working.

PS: Sorry for not giving you a more detailed answer right now, this is what I can give you at the moment :) Their page is very good though and I'm sure you will find the solution very easily!

Happy coding!

Comment: is this, correct where is written with muller for multer :)

Comment: you too, happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use PUT method instead of POST.
For using PUT you need to first install the method override module, which can be done as...
npm install method-override --save.